# Reset texting settings

Tags: settings, sms, google-voice

I have Google Voice on my Android and originally I didn't have texting, so I checked the box that has it send text from Google Voice all the time.  But recently my phone company just randomly gave me texting.  So I wish to be prompted every time I send a text message.  How can I reset my Droid so it asks what medium I wish to send my text from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `settings` > `Apps` > Click on the app that is being used as your default messaging medium (Google voice in your case) > Press `Clear defaults`.